# Caching part of canvas in custom view. Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-canvas, ondraw

I have extended **EditText** view with overridden **onDraw** method:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    int count = getLineCount();
    drawLineNumbers(canvas, count); // here I draw line numbers on canvas,
                                    // like on picture
    super.onDraw(canvas);
```

}

[image: Line number under red]

As we know, onDraw method of EditText calls very often, e.g. it calls for each indicator flashing - that's why redrawing all line numbers consume a lot of hardware resources.

Is there efficient method to cache part of canvas and do not redraw it every time? In my case I want to redraw it only when line's count changed. I have already tried save it in Bitmap, but on files with big amount of lines it throwing **OutOFMemmory** exception.

**Any thoughts are welcome.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a compound custom view:

```
class NumEditText extends LinearLayout
```

and add two views: left margin view with line numbers and an. associated EditText

EDIT:

try this skeleton:

```
public class NumberedEditText extends LinearLayout {

private LineNumbers lineNumbers;
private ET et;

public NumberedEditText(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);
    lineNumbers = new LineNumbers(context);
    et = new ET(context);
    addView(lineNumbers);
    addView(et, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
}

class LineNumbers extends View {
    private final static String TAG = "NumberedEditText.LineNumbers";
    public LineNumbers(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int fixed = 50;
        widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(fixed, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDraw ");
    }
}

class ET extends EditText implements TextWatcher {
    private final static String TAG = "NumberedEditText.ET";
    private Layout layout;
    private int cnt;

    public ET(Context context) {
    super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        addTextChangedListener(this);
        layout = getLayout();
        cnt = layout.getLineCount();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
        lineNumbers.scrollTo(l, t);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int before, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (layout.getLineCount() != cnt) {
            cnt = layout.getLineCount();
            lineNumbers.invalidate();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Sounds good. But how to synchronize scrolling, line height and so on? Could you please show some code snippet ?

Comment: Thank you. Nice idea and explanation.

Comment: Now I have tried it, and there one problem - scrollTo call onDraw method (even with removing invalidate() from onScrollChanged). So in big files scrolling works very slow. Maybe there are some things that will allowed to not invalidate View on scrolling?

Comment: not invalidate on scroll? it has no sense, you have to draw a new part of a view when scroll haopebs

Comment: I'm understanding, but in this case your idea not working. Because in big files all 1000+ numbers redrawing in UI thread and it cause scrolling stucks

Comment: why the heck you want to draw 1000+ numbers??? draw only numbers that are visible